# Change background color in mat-menu-panel

Tags: css, angular, typescript, less

I'm using angular 9 and less in my project.And I have a mat-menu-panel where my mat-menu-item is on that panel.I can change the color of my mat-menu-item a follows.

[image]

But How can I change the background color of the panel.i need to change the color of that white space.Please help

Comment: can you create a demo on stackblitz?

Comment: Inject element and show the mat-menu-item HTML and the CSS you tried for changing color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by changing the styles.less less file.

```
.mat-menu-panel.ng-trigger {
  background: transparent;
  min-width: 1%;
  min-height: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really provided enough clear information here but it is probably

```
.mat-menu-content{
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: There is no mat-menu-content suggestion in my code.only mat-menu-panel and mat-menu-item

Comment: if you provide the html then people might be able to help you (the html in chrome not in your project)